# PHP redefine constant without runkit or another way to declare a namespace

Tags: php

I am doing a framework similar to CodeIgniter but with namespaces. I don't want use runkit because many hosting providers don't have the extension.

The Namespaces are based on paths to the file class, if I who load the file class too I know the namespace has the class but I don´t know what sintax to use to declare the namespace.

I apologize for my english. I will try to explain me using a example:

```
namespace \FlexIgniter\Core

class Load {
  public function loadClass($name, $ns) {
     runkit_constant_redefine("NAMESPACE_AUTO", $ns);
     $path = $this->class2path($class);
     include_once($path);
  }
}
```

The file to load:

```
namespace NAMESPACE_AUTO;

class ToLoad {
  // do some stuff...
}
```

Thanks.

PS: https://github.com/Localnet/FlexIgniter

Comment: why would you need that?

Comment: I am trying to get implement in the framework MVC and HMVC the auto determination of the namespace facilitates convert a MVC (model, view, controller) to a HMVC module (changing the path) without have to edit the namespace of the model and controller.

Answer (score 0):

[Here are the requirements for PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md):

The following describes the mandatory requirements that must be adhered
to for autoloader interoperability.

### Mandatory

- A fully-qualified namespace and class must have the following
  structure `\<Vendor Name>\(<Namespace>\)*<Class Name>`
- Each namespace must have a top-level namespace ("Vendor Name").
- Each namespace can have as many sub-namespaces as it wishes.
- Each namespace separator is converted to a `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` when
  loading from the file system.
- Each `_` character in the CLASS NAME is converted to a
  `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. The `_` character has no special meaning in the
  namespace.
- The fully-qualified namespace and class is suffixed with `.php` when
  loading from the file system.
- Alphabetic characters in vendor names, namespaces, and class names may
  be of any combination of lower case and upper case.

### Examples

- `\Doctrine\Common\IsolatedClassLoader` => `/path/to/project/lib/vendor/Doctrine/Common/IsolatedClassLoader.php`
- `\Symfony\Core\Request` => `/path/to/project/lib/vendor/Symfony/Core/Request.php`
- `\Zend\Acl` => `/path/to/project/lib/vendor/Zend/Acl.php`
- `\Zend\Mail\Message` => `/path/to/project/lib/vendor/Zend/Mail/Message.php`

### Underscores in Namespaces and Class Names

- `\namespace\package\Class_Name` => `/path/to/project/lib/vendor/namespace/package/Class/Name.php`
- `\namespace\package_name\Class_Name` => `/path/to/project/lib/vendor/namespace/package_name/Class/Name.php`

The standards we set here should be the lowest common denominator for
painless autoloader interoperability. You can test that you are
following these standards by utilizing this sample SplClassLoader
implementation which is able to load PHP 5.3 classes.

### Example Implementation

Below is an example function to simply demonstrate how the above
proposed standards are autoloaded.

```
<?php

function autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    require $fileName;
}
```

### SplClassLoader Implementation

The following gist is a sample SplClassLoader implementation that can
load your classes if you follow the autoloader interoperability
standards proposed above. It is the current recommended way to load PHP
5.3 classes that follow these standards.

- http://gist.github.com/221634